# Firebase document add specific id on doc()

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to add a specific document id where:

```
ref = this.db.collection('sche').doc(`${xId}/${yId}`)
ref.set(data, {merge:true})
```

Im having problems on how to update that specific key ${yId}.

What am I Doing Wrong?

Comment: You cannot have another "/" in your document path because you entered a collection before that.

Comment: Sounds like the start of a good answer @creativecreatorormaybenot. :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the [limitations for Firestore collections, documents, and fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields):

> Constraints on document IDs
>
> - Must be valid UTF-8 characters
> - Must be no longer than 1,500 bytes
> - **Cannot contain a forward slash (/)**
> - Cannot solely consist of a single period (.) or double periods (..)
> - Cannot match the regular expression **.***

Basically, you're violating a documented limitation.